# Tweaks to a for loop in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a for loop I’m trying to beef up - but I'm pretty new to this, and my dart knowledge is failing me!

The code included is a boiled-down version of my page. In it, there’s a text field that takes numbers, and a couple of Text widgets which update based on some behind-the-scenes calculations, mostly within a four loop. Since I boiled it down so far, the page only works with digits 0-3, but hopefully you get the idea!

First task: when my main variable is changed, I'd like the loop to search through a particular List corresponding to that new value. So if the variable equals 1, it’ll search through list1. If it’s 2, it’ll search through list2, etc. So I’d simply like to inject the variable’s value into the List name being parsed through.

Second task: Each list contains some combination of digits. So the loops goes through values of i, from 0 to 2, and checks if the list being searched contains that number.

Last task: I have 2 bools, bool1 and bool2, which should correspond to if i is found in the List. If the list does contain i, I’d like that corresponding bool to be true. If not, it’s false.

For instance: User inputs "3." The for loop looks into list3. It finds the list contains 1 and 2. bool1 and bool2 are changed to "true," and the page is updated accordingly.

Hope this makes sense. Surely this is easy for Dart to accomplish yes?

Thanks for any help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const List<int> list0 = [];
const List<int> list1 = [1];
const List<int> list2 = [2];
const List<int> list3 = [1, 2];

class LoopTest extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'loop_test_screen';

  const LoopTest({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoopTest> createState() => _LoopTestState();
}

class _LoopTestState extends State<LoopTest> {
  int mainVariable = 0;
  bool bool1 = false;
  bool bool2 = false;
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: textController,
            onChanged: (val) {
              reRunLoop();
            },
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              const Text('Contains 1? '),
              Text('$bool1'),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              const Text('Contains 2? '),
              Text('$bool2'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void reRunLoop() {
    setState(
      () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
           list$mainVariable.contains(i)
           ? (bool[i] = true)
           : (bool[i] = false);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> So I’d simply like to inject the variable’s value into the List name being parsed through.

You need to use Lists of variables instead. You can't provide the variable name dynamically like list$mainVariable. Instead create a `List<List<int>> listOfLists` containing all of your lists, and do `listOfLists[mainVariable]`.

Similarly, for the booleans, you would need to create a `List<Bool> bools` and access each one like `bools[i]`.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! A list of lists makes total sense!